# Pig latin load ctrl+M delimited text

Tags: apache-pig, csv

I've lots of files (>100k) and each file has record that is ctrl+M delimited and \n separated. Within each field, the data is "pipe" delimited.
Pig treats ctrl+M as line separator when we use PigStorage().
I tried using TextLoader() and it showed the same behavior.
Any suggestions on how to run this in Pig? 
Preprocessing of files may not be feasible in this case.
Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Sample data:

`abc|^~\&|1100|7G^M0|1|2|3|4|5^Mpqr|^^^00|82|L`

Final Output (1 rows - ^M Delimiter):

`((abc,^~\&,1100,7G),(0,1,2,3,4,5)(pqr,^^^00,82,L))`

Comment: Can you paste some sample input data?

Comment: ok, what is your expected output from this data?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

**input:**

```
abc|^~\&|1100|7G^M0|1|2|3|4|5^Mpqr|^^^00|82|L
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line,'\\^M')) AS(col1:chararray,col2:chararray,col3:chararray);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(TOBAG(col1,col2,col3));
D = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0,'\\|'));
DUMP D;
```

**Output:**

```
(abc,^~\&,1100,7G)
(0,1,2,3,4,5)
(pqr,^^^00,82,L)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into this. I'm not sure if you have understood it. There is a ctrl+M character in the string. Here is the excerpt from Pig: Record Delimiters – For load statements Pig interprets the line feed ( '\n' ), carriage return ( '\r' or CTRL-M) and combined CR + LF ( '\r\n' ) characters as record delimiters (do not use these characters as field delimiters). For store statements Pig uses the line feed ('\n') character as the record delimiter. Source: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html

Comment: Yes , i misunderstood your question. Can you tell me what is the final output format for the above input?

Comment: I'm trying to get either \n as a line and then use STRSPLIT to split it based on ^M. Another option is to use ^M as the Delimiter and then use STRSPLIT on pipe data. I've updated the question with the final output.

Comment: Hi Sivaskthi, how are you typing ctrl+M character? I'm not sure if you are understanding the question. For simplicity sake, use the following example. `a^Mb^Mc` as your input data. Now use pig to load this data. `a = load 'sample.out' using PigStorage('\n') as (line:chararray); dump a;` when you run this, you will see 3 tuples in the data. PigStorage() doesn't consider ctrl+M as field delimiter and instead takes it as end of line.

Comment: Sorry for misleading. I updated the original post with the right output.